# Applying a patch, Android Gradle dependency

Tags: android, gradle, patch

I have this dependency in by build.gradle file:

```
 compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
```

This is for the StaggeredGridView compoenent in Android.

I'd like to apply a patch here, due to a known issue:

https://github.com/venkat230278/AndroidStaggeredGridViewOverscrollBug/blob/master/patch/sg.patch

How do i go about this?

Thanks

Comment: etsy library is getting deprecated. I suggest download whole library and add patch file into it using patch from VCS menu within Android Studio